# KeyListener not adding

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am pretty sure I am missing something pretty simple here, but I just can't find it!

Here is the declaration for my `GamePanel` class:

```
private class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
```

In its constructor is:

```
addKeyListener(this);
```

Also in the constructor:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    index ++;
                    index = index >= 15 ? 0 : index;
                    if (aPress) {
                        playerX --;
                    }
                    if (dPress) {
                        playerX ++;
                    }
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }

        }).start();
```

In the class:

```
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key pressed!");
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            aPress = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            dPress = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            aPress = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            dPress = false;
        }
    }
```

And finally:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
//set up f
f.add(new GamePanel());
f.setVisible(true);
```

I even added a `System.out.println` in my `keyPressed` method and it won't print! What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see `requestFocusInWindow()` or synchronized access to shared `keyPressed`. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod Ok, I will try that tomorrow; I am going to sleep now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyListener` is a fickle mistress.  The component where the `KeyListener` is registered must be focusable and must have focus in order for it to receive key events.

Try adding `setFocusable(true);` and `requestFocusInWindow();` after you have registered the listener.

A better idea would be to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), this will over come the focus issue.

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "a.pressed");
am.put("a.pressed", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        aPress = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for fickle mistress (oh yeah, also a bit for mentioning key bindings)

Answer (score 2):

Add `setFocusable(true);` to the GamePanel constructor.